# Kotlin optional parameter with Java backwards compatibility

Tags: java, kotlin, option-type, optional-parameters, backwards-compatibility

I'm currently writing a Kotlin library with an object having multiple methods requirering multiple optional parameters. Since in JAVA you would require to pass null to those parameters I think this is kind of unconfortable. Also overloading is not an solution as I don't know the possible combinations necessarily or there are ways to many possibilities.

```
class MyObj() {
    fun method1(param1: Int, param2: String? = null, param3: Int? = null): String { ... }
    fun method2(param1: Int, param2: Float? = null, param3: String? = null): Any { ... }
    fun method5(param1: Int, ...): User { ... }
}
```

In Kotlin I can simply write:

```
myObj = MyObj()
myObj.method1(param1 = 4711, param3 = 8850)
```

In Java I need to write:

```
MyObj myObj = new MyObj()
myObj.method1(4711, null, 8850)
...    
myObj.method5("abc", null, null, null, null, 8850, null, null, "def")
```

Since I have quite a lot of methods with a lot of optionals I thought about just passing a class for each method:

```
/** For JAVA backwards compatibility */
class Method1(
    val param1: Int
) {
    param2: String? = null
    param3: Int? = null

    fun withParam2(value: String) = apply { param2 = value }
    fun withParam3(value: Int) = apply { param3 = value }
}

class MyObj() {
    fun method1(param1: Int, param2: String? = null, param3: Int? = null): String { ... }
    
    /** For JAVA backwards compatibility */
    fun method1(values: Method1) = method1(values.param1, values.param2, values.param3)
}
```

So in Kotlin I can used named parameters and in Java I could simply write:

```
MyObj myObj = new MyObj()
myObj.method1(new Method1(4711).withParam3(8850))
```

From my point of view it looks fairly ugly because I always have to say `method1(new Method1())` or `method2(new Method2())`. **Do you think there is a more elegant version of this?**

Background: This is for calling a REST API taking lots of optional parameters.

Comment: Just to understand better, what is the inconvenience in passing `null` within a constructor? Since builders would also leave attributes `null` unless they are set.

Comment: It's not really inconvinient, just I don't like the look of it :)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java, the best way to handle a large amount of optional arguments is typically by some form of builder pattern. I would suggest one of two variants:

1: Return a chainable object and have some sort of "run" method at the end to take the provided arguments and run the actual method.

```
myObj.retrieveWhatever().from("abc").where(LESS_THAN, 3).setAsync(true).run();
```

2: For Java 8+, do the same, but in a lambda:

```
myObj.retrieveWhatever(args -> 
    args.from("abc").where(LESS_THAN, 3).setAsync(true)
);
```

...or, alternatively

```
myObj.retrieveWhatever(args -> {
    args.from("abc");
    args.where(LESS_THAN, 3);
    args.setAsync(true);
});
```

By doing it in a lambda, you remove the risk of forgetting the `.run()` call at the end.

Comment: Thank you, thats how I've done it now. Question concerning the second part of your answer. What do I need to do to utilize the lambda method in JAVA?

Answer (score 4):

You can just add `@JvmOverloads` annotation for the functions